# jquery group level validations

Tags: jquery, validation, validationrules

I am doing client side validation in jQuery. I have 3 fields and I want to write rules that  atleast one of these  fields should be filled. So I write a code like this.

```
"Address.FlatNo": {
    require_from_group: [1, ".building-group"],
    rangelength: [1, 50]
},
"Address.BuildingNo": {
    require_from_group: [1, ".building-group"],
    rangelength: [1, 50],
},
"Address.BuildingName": {
    require_from_group: [1, ".building-group"],
    rangelength: [1, 50]
},
```

And everything works fine. Now I want to add one more rule to these 3 fields that no fields can contains only whitespace. So I created a new validate method. and add that method in my rule. Now the code looks like

```
"Address.FlatNo": {
    require_from_group: [1, ".building-group"],
    rangelength: [1, 50],
    onlyspacecheck:true
},
"Address.BuildingNo": {
    require_from_group: [1, ".building-group"],
    rangelength: [1, 50],
    onlyspacecheck:true
},
"Address.BuildingName": {
    require_from_group: [1, ".building-group"],
    rangelength: [1, 50],
    onlyspacecheck:true
},
```

But here comes an issue. if one of 3 fields contains the whitespace then the error message is showing on every field. I don't know why. May be that behavior is because of using require_from_group or something else.

Please help!